# How to adjust col data in Latex tables automatically?

Tags: tables

Can someone tell me how to adjust the table's contents so that the last column is properly visible? This is for the document class thesis. Which you can find [here](https://github.com/Coding511/theis-cls-)

The MWE is given below with this cls.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside, openright]{Thesis}
\usepackage{lmodern,babel,adjustbox,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}




\begin{document}

\section{Summary of literature}
\begin{table}

    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{llll}
        \toprule
         References & Databases & Deep Learning Approach & Recognition Accuracy  \\
        \midrule
        T.Tuncer \cite{tuncer2021automated} &RAVDESS,EmoDB,SAVEE&Q-Wavelet Transform&87.43\%.90.09\%,79.08\%\\
        M.Mastaqeem \cite{sajjad2020clustering}&IEMOCAP,RAVDESS,EmoDB&Deep BiLSTM&72.25\%,85.57\%,77.02\%\\
        T.Anvarjon \cite{anvarjon2020deep}&IEMOCAP,EmoDB&Spectrogram based CNN&77.01\%,92.02\%\\
        S.Zhong \cite{zhong2020exploration}&IEMOCAP,EmoDB,CASIA&Fused feature&74.88\%,83.33\%,98.12\%\\
        
        S.Latif \cite{latif2020multi}&IEMOCAP&Multi-tasking with gender and speaker recognition&68.5\%\\        
        
        
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The corresponding pdf from above code is [image]

Is there any way to automatically adjust the col text? I tried `p{\width}`, but it is not working here. The edited result after using X instead of l is [image: this]
Regards

Comment: Use X instead of l. Like with TOC, index etc. needs a recompile. (All described in the tabularx documentation on ctan.org)

Comment: I m sorry for not getting your reply; which X are you pointing to?

Comment: For the column format. I suggest to read the tabularx documentation.

Comment: Sir tried that too; the result is overlapped text :( Uploaded that too in question itself sir.

Comment: For solutions please see the other answers. // A screenshot alone without code is quite useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have (at least) two issues in your table:

- `tabularx` table had to have at least one column of `X` or from it derived type
- words in text separated by commas should have empty space after commas.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside, openright]{Thesis}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\section{Summary of literature}
\begin{table}[ht] % 
\caption{Summary of Literature}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} lLLL @{}}
        \toprule
References  
    & Databases 
        & \makecell{Deep Learning\\ Approach} 
            & \makecell{Recognition\\ Accuracy}                     \\

        \midrule
T.Tuncer \cite{tuncer2021automated} 
    & RAVDESS, EmoDB, SAVEE
        & Q-Wavelet Transform   
            & \qty{87.43}{\%}. \qty{90.09}{\%}, \qty{79.08}{\%}     \\
        \addlinespace
M.Mastaqeem \cite{sajjad2020clustering}
    & IEMOCAP, RAVDESS, EmoDB
        & Deep BiLSTM
            & \qty{72.25}{\%}, \qty{85.57}{\%}, \qty{77.02}{\%}     \\
        \addlinespace
T.Anvarjon \cite{anvarjon2020deep}
    & IEMOCAP, EmoDB
        & Spectrogram based CNN
            & \qty{77.01}{\%}, \qty{92.02}{\%}                      \\
        \addlinespace
S.Zhong \cite{zhong2020exploration}
    & IEMOCAP, EmoDB, CASIA
        & Fused feature
            & \qty{74.88}{\%}, \qty{83.33}{\%}, \qty{98.12}{\%}     \\
        \addlinespace
S.Latif \cite{latif2020multi}
    & IEMOCAP   
        & Multi-tasking with gender and speaker recognition
            & \qty{68.5}{\%}                                        \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Off-topic*:

- For quantities (percentages) in table is use `siunitx` package.
- Added is option for table placement `[ht]` , so table is not pushed before section title.

**Addendum:**
In the case, that you prefer to use `tabularray` package, here is an alternative solution with use of `tblr` of `tabularray` package and table font size ˙\small`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{Thesis}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
\section{Summary of literature}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Summary of Literature}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} l X[l] X[1.1, l] X[l] @{}},
             row{1}  = {c, m},
             rows    = {font=\small\linespread{0.9}\selectfont}
            }
    \toprule
References 
    & Databases                 
        & Deep Learning Approach
            & {Recognition Accuracy}       \\
    \midrule
T.Tuncer \cite{tuncer2021automated}
    & RAVDESS, EmoDB, SAVEE
        & Q-Wavelet Transform
            & \qty{87.43}{\%}. \qty{90.09}{\%}, \qty{79.08}{\%}     \\
M.Mastaqeem \cite{sajjad2020clustering}
    & IEMOCAP, RAVDESS, EmoDB
        & Deep BiLSTM
            & \qty{72.25}{\%}, \qty{85.57}{\%}, \qty{77.02}{\%}     \\
T.Anvarjon \cite{anvarjon2020deep}
    & IEMOCAP, EmoDB
        & Spectrogram based CNN
            & \qty{77.01}{\%}, \qty{92.02}{\%}                      \\
S.Zhong \cite{zhong2020exploration}
    & IEMOCAP, EmoDB, CASIA
        & Fused feature
            & \qty{74.88}{\%}, \qty{83.33}{\%}, \qty{98.12}{\%}     \\
S.Latif \cite{latif2020multi}
    & IEMOCAP
        & Multi-tasking with gender and speaker recognition
            & \qty{68.5}{\%}                                        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Zarko and @Clara. @Zarko: What does it mean 'tabularx table had to have at least one column of X or from its derived type'? Also, using qualities for percentage is not affecting the display. right, sir? Also, this works for me. But @clara, I want exactly this, though I am getting this error "" File `tabularray.sty' not found. ^^M . Is there any alternative? Regards

Comment: @NITIndia, for `tabularx` read package documentation. It properly works only if at least one column is of `X` type. For `\qty˛`: compare result when you use it and when not. Between the is observable typographical difference. Please, message to Clara address to her, not to me (write below her answer) otherwise she may not see it. Alternative to `tabularray` is shoed in my answer,

Answer (score 2):

## longtable

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{Thesis}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\section{Summary of literature}
\begin{tblr}
[
long,
caption        = {Summary of Literature},
label          = {tblr:test},
]
{
rowhead        = 1,
colspec        = {Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
hline{1,Z}     = {.08em},
hline{2}       = {.05em},
rows           = {font=\footnotesize},
row{even[2-Z]} = {gray9!40}
}
References                              & Databases                 & Deep Learning Approach                               & {Recognition\\Accuracy}     \\
T.Tuncer \cite{tuncer2021automated}     & {RAVDESS\\EmoDB\\SAVEE}   & Q-Wavelet Transform                                  & {87.43\%\\90.09\%\\79.08\%} \\
M.Mastaqeem \cite{sajjad2020clustering} & {IEMOCAP\\RAVDESS\\EmoDB} & Deep BiLSTM                                          & {72.25\%\\85.57\%\\77.02\%} \\
T.Anvarjon \cite{anvarjon2020deep}      & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB}          & Spectrogram based CNN                                & {77.01\%\\92.02\%}          \\
S.Zhong \cite{zhong2020exploration}     & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB\\CASIA}   & Fused feature                                        & {74.88\%\\83.33\%\\98.12\%} \\
S.Latif \cite{latif2020multi}           & IEMOCAP                   & {Multi-tasking with gender\\and speaker recognition} & 68.50\%                     \\
T.Tuncer \cite{tuncer2021automated}     & {RAVDESS\\EmoDB\\SAVEE}   & Q-Wavelet Transform                                  & {87.43\%\\90.09\%\\79.08\%} \\
M.Mastaqeem \cite{sajjad2020clustering} & {IEMOCAP\\RAVDESS\\EmoDB} & Deep BiLSTM                                          & {72.25\%\\85.57\%\\77.02\%} \\
T.Anvarjon \cite{anvarjon2020deep}      & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB}          & Spectrogram based CNN                                & {77.01\%\\92.02\%}          \\
S.Zhong \cite{zhong2020exploration}     & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB\\CASIA}   & Fused feature                                        & {74.88\%\\83.33\%\\98.12\%} \\
S.Latif \cite{latif2020multi}           & IEMOCAP                   & {Multi-tasking with gender\\and speaker recognition} & 68.50\%                     \\
T.Tuncer \cite{tuncer2021automated}     & {RAVDESS\\EmoDB\\SAVEE}   & Q-Wavelet Transform                                  & {87.43\%\\90.09\%\\79.08\%} \\
M.Mastaqeem \cite{sajjad2020clustering} & {IEMOCAP\\RAVDESS\\EmoDB} & Deep BiLSTM                                          & {72.25\%\\85.57\%\\77.02\%} \\
T.Anvarjon \cite{anvarjon2020deep}      & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB}          & Spectrogram based CNN                                & {77.01\%\\92.02\%}          \\
S.Zhong \cite{zhong2020exploration}     & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB\\CASIA}   & Fused feature                                        & {74.88\%\\83.33\%\\98.12\%} \\
S.Latif \cite{latif2020multi}           & IEMOCAP                   & {Multi-tasking with gender\\and speaker recognition} & 68.50\%                     \\
T.Tuncer \cite{tuncer2021automated}     & {RAVDESS\\EmoDB\\SAVEE}   & Q-Wavelet Transform                                  & {87.43\%\\90.09\%\\79.08\%} \\
M.Mastaqeem \cite{sajjad2020clustering} & {IEMOCAP\\RAVDESS\\EmoDB} & Deep BiLSTM                                          & {72.25\%\\85.57\%\\77.02\%} \\
T.Anvarjon \cite{anvarjon2020deep}      & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB}          & Spectrogram based CNN                                & {77.01\%\\92.02\%}          \\
S.Zhong \cite{zhong2020exploration}     & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB\\CASIA}   & Fused feature                                        & {74.88\%\\83.33\%\\98.12\%} \\
S.Latif \cite{latif2020multi}           & IEMOCAP                   & {Multi-tasking with gender\\and speaker recognition} & 68.50\%                     \\
\end{tblr}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## table float

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{Thesis}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\section{Summary of literature}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Summary of Literature}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec        = {Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
hline{1,Z}     = {.08em},
hline{2}       = {.05em},
rows           = {font=\footnotesize},
row{even[2-Z]} = {gray9!40}
}
References                              & Databases                 & Deep Learning Approach                               & {Recognition\\Accuracy}     \\
T.Tuncer \cite{tuncer2021automated}     & {RAVDESS\\EmoDB\\SAVEE}   & Q-Wavelet Transform                                  & {87.43\%\\90.09\%\\79.08\%} \\
M.Mastaqeem \cite{sajjad2020clustering} & {IEMOCAP\\RAVDESS\\EmoDB} & Deep BiLSTM                                          & {72.25\%\\85.57\%\\77.02\%} \\
T.Anvarjon \cite{anvarjon2020deep}      & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB}          & Spectrogram based CNN                                & {77.01\%\\92.02\%}          \\
S.Zhong \cite{zhong2020exploration}     & {IEMOCAP\\EmoDB\\CASIA}   & Fused feature                                        & {74.88\%\\83.33\%\\98.12\%} \\
S.Latif \cite{latif2020multi}           & IEMOCAP                   & {Multi-tasking with gender\\and speaker recognition} & 68.50\%                     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @zarko could you please help me adding \caption and \label inside this method using longtblr please.

Comment: @NITIndia I have updated my answer.